downloading a web page using TCL/tk
Here is some legacy code I copied from long ago. The command url  is supposed to print off the contents of a web page.
proc url {String} {
  package require http
  package require tls
  ::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -request 1 -ssl2 0 -ssl3 0 -tls1 1 -cafile VeriSignClass3SecureServerCA-G3.crt]
  set token [::http::geturl $String]
  upvar #0 $token state
  puts [$state(body)] }

I try url "https://shenlanguage.org/TBoS/Programs/3.3.txt" and get this
invalid command name "(define factorial .... "
So the web page is being downloaded but treated as a command? What's wrong here?
I hoped to print the contents off the page.

Changing puts [$state(body)] for return [::http::data $token] works for me:
proc url {String} {
    package require http
    package require tls
    ::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -request 1 -ssl2 0 -ssl3 0 -tls1 1 -cafile VeriSignClass3SecureServerCA-G3.crt]

    set token [::http::geturl $String]
    upvar #0 $token state
    return [::http::data $token]
}

Output:
% url "https://shenlanguage.org/TBoS/Programs/3.3.txt"
(define factorial 
   X -> (factorialh X 1))

(define factorialh 
   0 Accum -> Accum 
   X Accum -> (factorialh (- X 1) (* X Accum))) 

(define plus 
   X 0 -> X  
   X Y -> (+ 1 (plus X (- Y 1)))) 

(define fib 
   0 -> 0  
   1 -> 1  
   X -> (+ (fib (- X 1)) (fib (- X 2))))

(define even? 
   1 -> false  
   X -> (odd? (- X 1)))

(define odd?  
   1 -> true  
   X -> (even? (- X 1)))



%


That's a good answer but I need the output in the form of a string.

It is a string: puts [string length [url https://shenlanguage.org/TBoS/Programs/3.3.txt]] -> 393 http::data is a shorcut to $state(body)
